# script insert SQL Server 2005 from SQL Server 2014 Express

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2005

I have a database in SQL Server 2014 Express, and I want to import it to SQL Server 2005.

I have generated the scripts to generate the database and to insert the data. All the script generated to be compatible with SQL Server 2005.

I have problems when inserting datetime. I get this error:

> Msg 8115, Level 16, State 8, Line 2
>   Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type Numeric.

The datetime exported from SQL Server 2014 is:

```
CAST(N'2018-10-22 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime)
```

`YYYY-DD-MM` works if I edited the query, but it’s a big database

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the client date format when you do the INSERT.

```
SET DATEFORMAT ymd
```

Run this as the first line in the script that inserts the data, and this will tell the client to interpret the date correctly as YEAR-MONTH-DATE as it is formatted in the script.

Comment: I found this post at the same time as your answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26971328/ms-sql-server-2012-exports-datetime-as-script-which-it-cannot-import
THANKS